# Webfont generator - Problem with greek letter "μ"

Tags: fonts, webfonts

i've tried using Squirrelfont's webfont generator to convert some greek fonts to webfonts. Everything seems to be working, the only problem is that the letter "μ" (small-case) does not display in the converted webfont.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I’d double check is whether or not the typeface has that character coverage in the first place—I’m guessing you already did, but just thought I’d mention it because that’s not always the case.

I did a quick test with the typeface with the test Fira GO, which does include the μ. When using the Font Squirrel’s Basic or Optimal settings, it seems it will subset the file down to their “Western languages” character coverage.

If you switch to the Expert setting, you can change the Subsetting option to Custom and choose specific groups to keep, ex. Greek, Math symbols, etc. or you can choose No Subsetting to keep everything.

[image: Screenshot of Font Squirrel’s subsetting options]

Hope that’s helpful!